# Is there a way to create visible files on google drive?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I'm using Drive Api to make users upload and store files on their Google Drive accounts. As I see for now, every file that user uploads is hidden under my app and can not be displayed on drive without my app. I want them to display the files they upload just like regular images, videos etc. on Google Drive.

Is there a way to accomplish this feature?

**EDITED:**

I would like to add a solution for this problem to help programmers who visit this page.

Let's create the folder we want to store our files inside:

```dart
    var client = GoogleHttpClient(await account.authHeaders);
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    ga.File fileMetadata = ga.File();
    fileMetadata.name = "ourFolderName";
    fileMetadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    var response = await drive.files.create(fileMetadata);
    print("response file id: ${response.id}");
    writeFolderID(response.id);
```

writeFolderID method contains some codes that writes the ID to local db for further usage in app.

When I try to upload something, I gotta add folderID to file.parents field in our File variable. Then create the file in drive.

```dart
    var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
    var file = await FilePicker.getFile();


    String folderID = await getFolderID("folderKey"); //getFolderID is a function that retrieves folderID we have created before.
// In order to upload a file to a folder in drive api, we have to save the folderID at creation moment. 


    fileToUpload.parents = [folderID];
    fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);
    var response = await drive.files.create(
    fileToUpload,
    uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
    );
```

Afterwards, you can display "ourFolderName" in Google Drive easily and can make interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. When I am specifying the parent folders and metadata, I should have left the parent folder blank as it is stated in description of variable.

### The IDs of the parent folders which contain the file. If not specified as part of a create request, the file will be placed directly in the user's My Drive folder. If not specified as part of a copy request, the file will inherit any discoverable parents of the source file. Update requests must use the addParents and removeParents parameters to modify the parents list.

I hope it helps anyone who visited this page.